# How to insert code into function using a stringed equation?

Tags: python

I programmed some code to evaluate 2d functions (ones with 2d inputs and 2d outputs), but I don't know how to put equations that are defined as strings in a function definition.
So for example if I have the code

```
eq = "x**2"
def func(x):
    return eval(eq)

for i in range(100000):
    print(func(i))
```

The reason I need to evaluate is because I want the string version so I can save it to a csv file afterwards and I dont want to have to manually type the equations in both places every time. So if you run this code, it runs a lot slower than:

```
def func(x):
    return x**2

for i in range(100000):
    print(func(i))
```

even though these essentially are the same thing. So my question is: Is there a way to, on the function definition, actually like INSERT the equation into the return as if it was actually just typed there in the first place? Because right now it is just coming to the eval() statement, looking at the string, then evaluating it which takes a long time when I want it to put the equation into the definition and just know what it is every time it comes across the function call.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about something like this `return x**2, 'x**2'` where it returns the value and the actual string representation?

Comment: No i mean like i want the return to be return x**2 but the eval takes the place of the x**2 as if i had typed it out in the first place

Comment: So you want to dynamically create a function from a string?

Comment: I think something like `exec('def f(x): return x**2')` would actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you means accelerating `eval` execution performance, I think you can try `lambda` tricks:

```
In[1]: import random

In[2]: eq = "x**2"

# original time:
In[3]: % timeit random.random() ** 2
222 ns ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

# use eval
In[4]: def func1(x): return eval(eq)

In[5]: % timeit func1(random.random())
5.7 µs ± 434 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# use lambda to accelerate
In[6]: func2 = eval('lambda x: ' + eq)

In[7]: % timeit func2(random.random())
273 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

it is close to original code, 20 times faster than `eval`

Comment: I got it to work with the eval("lambda x:" + eq) thank you so much! I got the run time of the program from about 20 seconds to about 9!

Comment: glad to help you : )

Answer (score 1):

If the function consists only of that equation, which is the return value, and nothing else, your can create it from the equation with a `lambda` like this:

```
def func_from_eq(eq):
    return eval('lambda x : ({eq}, "{eq}")'.format(eq=eq))

func = func_from_eq("x**2")
func(3)   # returns (9, "x**2")
```

It uses `eval`, too, but only once when creating the function. After that it's "compiled" code same way a `def` with a hardcoded equation was.

---

If your equation is not the full story, i.e. there's more code than just that, you could make a decorator which always adds a defined equation to your return value:

```
from functools import wraps

def add_eq(eq):
    """ Decorator that packs the return value of a function
        into a tuple together with the value eq (typically str). """
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs), eq                        
        return wrapped        
    return decorator

@add_eq("x**2")
def func(x):
    return x**2
```

But whether that's very pretty is discussable. It too has the drawback that you need to write your equation redundantly, in the code and in the decorator call, always forced to keep them sync'ed.

Answer (score 0):

I use eval in lambda to create functions dynamically!

Get the string from your source and use lambda to get your custom function

```
eqtn = "x+y*10"
fn = lambda x,y : eval(eqtn);
fn(x,y)
```

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXKTp.png)